# Can a std::unique_ptr be reassigned such that its old value is destroyed *before* the new one is constructed?

Tags: c++, destructor, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I'm interested in updating an old personal project to modern C++. I appreciate how RAII simplifies cleanup: instead of making a `new` object and remembering to `delete` it before every return point in a function, just `make_unique` and it will be destroyed appropriately. But I have one nitpick when comparing the generated assembly.

Say there's a class method that replaces one of its `unique_ptr` members with a new value:

```cpp
// std::unique_ptr<int> MyClass::m_foo;
void MyClass::refresh_foo(int x) {
    m_foo = std::make_unique<int>(x * 3 + 5);
}
```

This will create a `new` `int`, assign it to `m_foo`, and then `delete` the old value of `m_foo`. But that's not quite the same as the old behavior, which could `delete` the old value, then create a `new` one and assign it to `m_foo`:

```cpp
// int *MyClass::m_foo;
void MyClass::refresh_foo(int x) {
    delete m_foo;
    m_foo = new int(x * 3 + 5);
}
```

From the [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/Y963hraqa), gcc, clang, and MSVC all generate less code for the old way than the new one. I understand why this is the case, since that's the order in which all expressions are evaluated; `p = q;` has to construct `q` first. And of course `m_foo` had an invalid value in between the `delete` and `new` lines. But is there a way I'm missing to have `unique_ptr` destroy its old value and then create a new one in one expression? A "`replace_unique`"? Seems like it would be helpful when dealing with large objects so two of them don't needlessly coexist.

**Edit:** To be clear, I'm just using `int` as a trivial example here. My actual use cases are with classes of my own or from a library. And `m_foo.reset(new int(x * 3 + 5));` naturally has the same problem compared to the old way of doing things, since it too has to construct the `new` `int` before assigning it and `delet`ing the previous one.

Comment: How about m_foo.reset(new int(x * 3 + 5)) ?

Comment: Why are you allocating a new object at all, anyway? Why not just `*m_foo = x*3 + 5`?

Comment: @SeverinPappadeux both reset() and operator= update the held pointer to point at the new object before destroying the old object. The OP wants the opposite.

Comment: Note that the two behaviors are not equivalent. If an exception occurs in `new int(...)`, the so-called "old behavior" leaves `m_foo = nullptr`, whereas the `m_foo = std::make_unique(...)` leaves `m_foo` unchanged.

Comment: @RaymondChen actually, in the "old behavior", an exception in `new int` will leave `m_foo` *dangling* since the previous `int` was destroyed but the pointer is unchanged, not null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`unique_ptr::reset()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/reset) to deterministically destroy the currently held object when you want. Update the `unique_ptr` with a `nullptr` pointer before then updating it with a new object pointer, eg:

```cpp
// std::unique_ptr<int> MyClass::m_foo;
void MyClass::refresh_foo(int x) {
    m_foo.reset(); // <- int is destroyed here
    m_foo = std::make_unique<int>(x * 3 + 5);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! m_foo.reset() and m_foo = nullptr both generate identical code. Interestingly, gcc and clang both leave a second delete call at the end, "just in case" m_foo needs destroying again. Which is just standards compliance according to stackoverflow.com/questions/45689690.

Answer (score 0):

I accepted the answer which calls `m_foo.reset()` before `m_foo = std::make_unique<int>(...)` because it's the simplest way to solve the problem as stated: destroying the original value before constructing the new one. However, that does result in an extra `delete` call which shouldn't be necessary and is less optimal than the "pre-modern" way of using raw pointers.

This method, at least in [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/oG33Wdo9T) with `-Ofast`, avoids the second `delete` call, and only has one extra `mov` instruction compared to the old way (explicitly setting `m_foo` to `nullptr` before assigning its newly constructed value):

```cpp
// std::unique_ptr<int> MyClass::m_foo;
void refresh_smart(int x) {
    m_foo = nullptr;
    auto new_foo = std::make_unique<int>(x * 3 + 5);
    m_foo.swap(new_foo);
    new_foo.release(); // no memory leak since it's null
}
```

As a reusable template function:

```cpp
template<typename T, typename... Ps>
void remake_unique(std::unique_ptr<T> &p, Ps... args) {
    p = nullptr;
    auto new_p = std::make_unique<T>(args...);
    p.swap(new_p);
    new_p.release();
}

// std::unique_ptr<int> MyClass::m_foo;
void refresh_smart(int x) {
    remake_unique(m_foo, x * 3 + 5);
}
```

Comment: The `swap()` and `release()` is not necessary, since `m_foo` is `nullptr` at that point, so this is merely setting `m_foo` to the new object in `new_foo` and setting `new_foo` to `nullptr`, thus making the subsequent `release()` redundant. This is really no better than just moving the result of `make_unique()` into `m_foo` directly. You really shouldn't be striving to replicate the "old" behavior, as it was incorrect to begin with. Use `unique_ptr` the way it is meant to be used. If your code relies on the order of destructions, then you have bigger problems to deal with.

Comment: I see, thanks. You're right, I'm not depending on the order of destructors here, and apart from that order, the assembly for `m_foo = make_unique()` is just as good as the "old" behavior (and better than if I do `new_foo = make_unique(); delete m_foo; m_foo = new_foo` to have the same construct-new/destroy-old order). <https://godbolt.org/z/6M596a3s7>

Comment: (Comparing all three approaches: https://godbolt.org/z/x3vr74b95)